# AngularJS jQuery File Upload Plugin Errors in a $Dialog Service Box

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui

I am working on implementing the AngularJS code of the jquery file upload plugin found: http://blueimp.github.io/jQuery-File-Upload/ within a $dialog box using the $dialog bootstrap directive found: http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/dialog

Everything is working as expected, modal comes up fine, files upload fine, etc... The issue is that when the modal is closed, 3 errors come up and then anytime the modal is opened or closed after that they continue to show on console.  They are:

```
cannot call methods on fileupload prior to initialization; attempted to call method 'processing'
cannot call methods on fileupload prior to initialization; attempted to call method 'active'
cannot call methods on fileupload prior to initialization; attempted to call method 'progress'
```

I can see where the errors *might* be occuring, I am just not sure why or how to resolve these issues.  Thanks!

Here's a plnkr with the associated issues.
http://plnkr.co/edit/vQUpJGBPGNNKsU91qIG3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has been resolved in the newest version of the plugin, going back to utilizing just the data-fileupload param.

The plunker has been updated to reflect this.

Answer (score 3):

You should use `ng-attr-data-fileupload="options"` instead of `data-fileupload="options"` in `user-photo-tpl.html`. But in order for this to work you should upgrade your angular to latest version. This ng-attr-* allows the attribute to be added to DOM element after it has been resolved.

Comment: Takes care of the errors, however then after adding a file to upload it does not add the file.  *Edit* Updated the plunker to show this.